# Explicit conversion on function parameter

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2015, type-conversion, windows-7-x64

I would like to know what the correct way is to explicitly convert the value passed to the cbData parameter of the RegSetValueW function. The wcslen function and sizeof operator return size_t which appears to have 8 bytes on Windows 64-bit.

```
WINADVAPI
LSTATUS
APIENTRY
RegSetKeyValueW (
    _In_        HKEY     hKey,
    _In_opt_    LPCWSTR  lpSubKey,
    _In_opt_    LPCWSTR  lpValueName,
    _In_        DWORD    dwType,
    _In_reads_bytes_opt_(cbData) LPCVOID  lpData,
    _In_        DWORD    cbData
    );

PCWSTR pwszRegistryData = L"Stuff";

RegSetKeyValueW( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"RegistrySubKey",
                 L"RegistryValue", REG_SZ, pwszRegistryData,
                 (wcslen( pwszRegistryData ) + 1) * sizeof( WCHAR ) );
```

**Method 1**–explicitly convert them both (it seems a bit over-cautious):

```
(DWORD)(wcslen( pwszRegistryData ) + 1) * (DWORD)sizeof( WCHAR )
```

**Method 2**–only explicitly convert the result:

```
(DWORD)((wcslen( pwszRegistryData ) + 1) * sizeof( WCHAR ))
```

**Method 3**–depend on implicit conversion to do its job:

```
(wcslen( pwszRegistryData ) + 1) * sizeof( WCHAR )
```

**Real world result:**

Compiler optimizations tell me to take a hike because the result in binary code is a numeric constant.

**Edit:**

If the length of pwszRegistryData is exceedingly long or will be determined during run time, the approach mentioned by RbMm seems the way to go. Thank you for your suggestion.

I do have one more question; the following call to RegSetKeyValueW does not produce a compilation warning:

```
// On x64 platform: typedef unsigned long long size_t;

RegSetKeyValueW( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"RegistrySubKey",
                 L"RegistryValue", REG_SZ, pwszRegistryData,
                 (DWORD)(wcslen( pwszRegistryData ) + 1) * sizeof( WCHAR ) );
```

While the following example does produce a 'possible loss of data' warning:

```
void func( unsigned long durrr ){}


unsigned long long herp = 5, derp = 2;

func( (unsigned long)(herp + 1) * derp );
```

From my understanding, both function calls should produce a compilation warning. Why does the compiler seem to behave biased?

Comment: Just use a static cast (`static_cast<DWORD>(...)`). The registry doesn't support values over 4GB anyway.

Comment: @Johnathan This is C, not C++.

Comment: if `wcslen(pwszRegistryData) < 0x7FFFFFFF` result of 1 or 2 will be the same. otherwise still will be an error. so no different 1 or 2. 3 is the same as 2 + compiler warning. if want be absolutely precise use `size_t len = wcslen(pwszRegistryData);
 LONG err = len < MAXLONG ? RegSetKeyValueW(.., ((ULONG)len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)) : ERROR_INVALID_DATA;`